# Plotly Dash Graph not refreshing automatically

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I am looking for some help here. I created an live graph, reading data from my csv file.
Once i change the content of source csv file, automatic refresh is not happening. Instead if i refresh the browser it will update the graph.

Can you please provide me solution so it will directly update the graph without manual interventions.
Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly
import random
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from collections import deque
import pandas as pd



app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H4('Stock_Data_Streaming'),
        dcc.Graph(id='live-graph', animate=True), 
        dcc.Interval(
            id='graph-update',
            interval=1*100,
            n_intervals=0
        )
    ]
)

@app.callback(Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
              [Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals')])


def update_graph_ohlc(n):


    df = pd.read_csv('/Users/371970/Downloads/Test_Data/NIFTY_BANK.csv')

    X = df['Date']


    data = go.Ohlc(x=df['Date'],
                    open=df['Col_Open'],
                    high=df['Col_High'],
                    low=df['Col_Low'],
                    close=df['Col_Close']
                  )


    layout = go.Layout(
                    title = "OHLC Testing Chart",
                    xaxis = dict(title = "Date"),
                    yaxis = dict(title = "Values in K")
        )



    return {'data': [data],'layout' : [layout]}



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()



Source Data:

Date,Col_Open,Col_High,Col_Low,Col_Close,Col_Volume
27/01/20 9:15,31110.55,31117.1,31007.8,31087.6,0
27/01/20 9:16,31077.05,31093.65,31074.85,31088,0
27/01/20 9:17,31093.55,31103.45,31077.9,31085.75,0
27/01/20 9:18,31089.35,31094.9,31061.75,31071.8,0
27/01/20 9:19,31075.1,31075.1,31043.25,31051.15,0
27/01/20 9:20,31057.75,31057.75,30998.35,31016.2,0
27/01/20 9:21,31012.4,31018.35,30992.5,30996.65,0
27/01/20 9:22,30997.25,31002.2,30969.4,30971.9,0
27/01/20 9:23,30973.2,30994,30970.6,30992.15,0
27/01/20 9:24,30991.8,30991.8,30934.15,30934.5,0
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, my Plotly Express figures were not updating, even though the callbacks were called as I expected them to be. Removing `animate=True` fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Could not figure out why my candle stick data would not update. "animate=False" worked for me as well