# Plotly Dash Graph Requires Page Refresh to Update

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to update a go.Figure by overwriting the data with new (scatter) traces. This figure is displayed in my Dash dashboard and automatically reloaded using an interval. However, when I update the figure, it stops updating the plot (updated points or newly added points afterwards are not displayed) and becomes non-interactive in the dashboard (hovering over points does not bring up hover text, cannot drag and zoom, etc.). The updating of the go.Figure in the backend is working as expected, as I can interact with the updated plot just fine upon reloading the page. Updating of the go.Figure is called from the backend, the function call for this is omitted from the below code.

(To my knowledge) there are no exceptions being thrown or logged by my code.

I have found a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60538474/plotly-dash-graph-not-refreshing-automatically) describing the same issue as I am having. The solution marked in this post suggests setting the animate property of the dcc.Graph objects to False, however, this does not solve my issue.

Here's my code:

Dashboard:

```
from embedding_projector.projector.embedding_projector import EmbeddingProjector
from embedding_projector.projector.projector_plot_manager import ProjectorPlotManager
from embedding_projector.projector.plots_enum import PlotsEnum
from dashboard.dahsboard_settings import DashboardSettings
from dashboard.dashboard_layout import DashboardLayout


_registered_projectors : dict[str, EmbeddingProjector] = {}
_active_projector : EmbeddingProjector = None
_active_plot_manager : ProjectorPlotManager = None

_clicked_plot : PlotsEnum = None

class Dashboard():
    _settings : DashboardSettings = DashboardSettings()
    
    def __init__(self, settings : DashboardSettings) -> None:
        global _settings
        _settings = settings

        global _layout
        self.app.layout = DashboardLayout(settings).get_layout()


    # NOTE Multiple callbacks for single output: https://community.plotly.com/t/multiple-callbacks-for-an-output/51247
    app = DashProxy(__name__, prevent_initial_callbacks=True, transforms=[MultiplexerTransform()])
    app.logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    app.layout = dbc.Container()

    @app.callback(
        [Output('latest-model-plot', 'figure'),
        Output('previous-model-plot', 'figure')],
        Input('refresh-graph-interval', 'n_intervals')
    )
    def refresh_graph_interval(n_intervals):
        if _active_plot_manager is not None:
            latest_model_plot, previous_model_plot = _active_plot_manager.get_plots()
            return latest_model_plot, previous_model_plot
        return no_update, no_update

    def register_projector(self, projector : EmbeddingProjector):
            _registered_projectors[projector.id] = projector
    
    def set_active_projector(self, projector_id):
        global _active_projector
        global _active_plot_manager
        _active_projector = _registered_projectors[projector_id]
        _active_plot_manager = _active_projector.get_plot_manager()
```

Dashbaord Layout:

```
from dash import html, dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc 
from dashboard.dahsboard_settings import DashboardSettings


class DashboardLayout():
    _settings : DashboardSettings
    
    def __init__(self, settings : DashboardSettings):
        self._settings = settings

    def get_layout(self):
        return dbc.Container([
            html.Link(
                rel='stylesheet',
                href='./assets/styling.css'
            ),

            html.Div(className="graph-column",
                children=[
                    dcc.Interval(id="refresh-graph-interval", disabled=False, interval=self._settings.graph_refresh_rate_ms),
                    dcc.Graph(id='latest-model-plot', figure={}, animate=False),
                    dcc.Graph(id='previous-model-plot', figure={}, animate=False),
                ]
            ),

        ...
    ])
```

Plotting:

```
import time
import random
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import copy
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

from pyparsing import Iterable
from projector.plot_settings import PlotSettings
from projector.plots_enum import PlotsEnum
from embedding_projector.utils.misc import *

class ProjectorPlotManager():
    name : str
    _latest_model_plot : go.Figure
    _labels_shown_in_legend_latest = []

    _previous_model_plot : go.Figure
    _labels_shown_in_legend_previous = []

    _labels_dict = {}
    _color_map = {}
    _settings : PlotSettings


    def __init__(self, name : str, settings : PlotSettings):
        self.name = name
        self._settings = settings
        self._resolve_label_settings()

        self._latest_model_plot = go.Figure()
        self._previous_model_plot = go.Figure()

    def _resolve_label_settings(self):
        self._labels_dict[-1] = self._settings.unclassified_label
        for i, label in enumerate(self._settings.labels):
            self._labels_dict[i] = label

        self._color_map[self._settings.unclassified_label] = self._settings.unclassified_label_color
        self._color_map.update(self._settings.label_colors)


    def get_plots(self):
        return self._latest_model_plot, self._previous_model_plot


    def get_labels(self):
        labels = [self._settings.unclassified_label]
        labels.extend(self._settings.labels)
        return labels
    
   
    def update_plots(self, data_new, time_points, labels = None, update_previous_plot : bool = False):
        if update_previous_plot and len(self._latest_model_plot.data) > 0:
            self._previous_model_plot = copy.deepcopy(self._latest_model_plot)
            self._labels_shown_in_legend_previous = self._labels_shown_in_legend_latest.copy()

        opacity_traces = self._get_opacity_traces()
        # if there are fewer traces in the latest plot, extend opacity_traces such that it matches the length of new_data
        if len(opacity_traces) < len(data_new):
            opacity_traces += [1] * (len(data_new) - len(opacity_traces))

        self._labels_shown_in_legend_latest.clear()
        labels = self._process_labels(labels)
        scatter_traces = self._create_scatter_traces(data_new, labels, time_points, self._labels_shown_in_legend_latest, opacity_traces)
        self._latest_model_plot.update(data=scatter_traces)


    def _create_scatter_traces(self, data : Iterable, labels, time_points : list[float], legend_labels : list[str], opacity_values : list[float] = None):
        scatter_traces = []
        for label, grouped_data in self._group_by_labels(data, labels, time_points, opacity_values):
            if label not in legend_labels:
                show_legend = True
                legend_labels.append(label)
            else: show_legend = False

            if label == self._settings.unclassified_label and show_legend:
                legend_rank = 1
            else: legend_rank = None

            label_color = self._color_map[label]
            for data_point in np.array(grouped_data):
                scatter_trace = self._create_scatter_trace(data_point, label, label_color, show_legend, legend_rank)
                scatter_traces.append(scatter_trace)
                if show_legend: show_legend = False # Only show the legend once for each label
        return scatter_traces


    def _create_scatter_trace(self, data : Iterable, label : str, label_color : str = None, show_legend : bool = False, legend_rank : int = None):
        x=data[0]
        y=data[1]
        time_point = data[3] # matches the index of the "timepoints" column of the data
        opacity = data[4] if data[4] is not None else 1
        
        return go.Scatter(
            x=[x],
            y=[y],
            mode='markers',
            text=f"{label}; T{time_point}",
            name=label,
            legendgroup=label,
            marker=dict(color=label_color),
            showlegend=show_legend,
            legendrank=legend_rank,
            opacity=opacity,
            ids = (time_point,),
            uid = get_trace_uid(x,y, time_point)
        )

    
    def _group_by_labels(self, data, labels : list[str], time_points : list[float], opacity_values : list[float]):
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df['labels'] = labels
        df['time_points'] = time_points
        df['opacity'] = opacity_values
        label_groupings = df.groupby('labels')
        return label_groupings


    # label count is only needed when labels is None, this will set the labels to the unclassified label
    def _process_labels(self, labels : Iterable, label_count : int = None) -> Iterable[str]:
        if labels is None:
            if label_count is None:
                raise Exception("Error processing labels: When labels is none, label_count needs to be provided.")
            return [self._settings.unclassified_label] * label_count
        
        labels = np.nan_to_num(labels, nan=-1)
        labels = list(map(lambda label: self._labels_dict[label], labels))

        for label in labels: 
            if label not in self._color_map:
                self._color_map[label] = self._get_random_plotly_color()

        return labels
    

    def _get_opacity_traces(self) -> list[float]:
        opacity_traces = []
        for trace in self._latest_model_plot.data:
            opacity_traces.append(trace.opacity)
        return opacity_traces


    def _get_random_plotly_color(self):
        colors_in_use = list(self._color_map.values())
        named_colors_list = list(mcolors.CSS4_COLORS.keys())
        if colors_in_use is not None and set(named_colors_list).issubset(set(colors_in_use)):
            raise Exception('all colors available to plotly are already being used')

        random_color = random.choice(named_colors_list)
        while colors_in_use is not None and random_color in colors_in_use:
            random_color = random.choice(named_colors_list)
        return random_color


def get_trace_uid(x_point : float, y_point : float, time_point : float) -> str:
    return f"X{x_point}Y{y_point}T{time_point}"
```